# Getting the Index of the selected item in jquery auto complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am using [jQuery autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete), as follows:

From my PHP file, I am get json encoded arrays - one for ids and one for names.

I fill the autocomplete with names. In the `select` function, I am able to correctly alert
the selected item, but I am not able to get the index of the selected item. How do I get it?

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_data.php",
        success: function(data) {
            data_array = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            $("#my_autocomplete").autocomplete({
                source: data_array.names,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.item);
                }
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hY5Wt/

Instead of two arrays, you could have one array of objects.  Each object would have a label and index: `{label:"First", idx:1}`.  The autocomplete will use the label to display and on select event, you can access ui.item.idx to get the identifier/index.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   source: [{label:"First", idx:1},
            {label:"Second", idx:2},
            {label:"Third", idx:3}],
   select: function(event, ui) { alert(ui.item.idx); }
});
```

You link to an autocomplete plugin, but your code looks like you are using jQuery UI.

Comment: Is it possible to show in text box only one field? (not necessarily this is label field)?